# POST request saving all values to one column

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman, h2

I'm using Postman to send a POST request with some values(I put two strings, one is for username and the other is for mail), but all data gets saved to first column ("username").
What am I doing wrong?[image]

This is what I've tried.

```
{
    "username": "mm46676",
    "mail": "mm46676@gmail.com"
}
```

I expected mm46676 is going to be saved in username column and mm46676@gmail.com to be saved in mail column.
I'm using H2 console to see how it was saved in db.
[image]

EmployeeController.java

```
import com.incompatibleTypes.plancation.plancationapp.model.Employee;
import com.incompatibleTypes.plancation.plancationapp.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Employee> showAllEmployees(){
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/add")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewEmployee (@RequestBody String username, String mail){
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setUsername(username);
        employee.setMail(mail);
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
        return "Employee Saved!";
    }
}
```

Employee model(if it can help in any way)

```
package com.incompatibleTypes.plancation.plancationapp.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;


import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    private Role role;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "mail")
    private String mail;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "minimal_vacation_day_id") 
    private VacationDay minimalVacationDay;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "employee_bonusvacdays",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bonus_vacation_day_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    )
    private Set<BonusVacationDay> bonusVacationDays = new HashSet<>();
    private LocalDateTime dateEmployed;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is when passing the request body as a method parameter. With this code:

```
public @ResponseBody String addNewEmployee (@RequestBody String username, String mail)
```

the whole JSON body goes as a String to the variable `username`. You should pass an object with fields `username` and `mail` instead. This can be the entity or - even better - a dedicated POJO aka as DTO. Something like this:

```
public @ResponseBody String addNewEmployee (@RequestBody EmployeeDTO data) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setUsername(data.getUsername());
    employee.setMail(data.getMail());
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
    return "Employee Saved!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I appreciate the quick answer.
If I have an employee POJO, do i also create an EmployeeDTO?

Comment: DTO is not obligatory. You can use the entity as well. But it is recommended because not all fields of an entity should be exposed to the remote interface. And it is more flexible as you can even combine fields of different entities in one DTO. Check this for more details: https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern

Comment: Thanks a lot!
You're a Legend 
:)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@RequestBody` in controller with String, in this case whole your input becomes just a string. Try to replace like this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/add")
public @ResponseBody String addNewEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
   employeeRepository.save(employee);
   return "Employee Saved!";
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Now it does what I wanted.
Cheers mate!